# Start browserSync and make it open a new chrome instance without gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using a normal npm script. I want to start browserSync and open a google chrome instance without gulp.

Here is the nodejs script - a file called tools/dist-server.js:

```
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var historyApiFallback = require('connect-history-api-fallback');

browserSync.init({
    port: 3000,
    ui: {
        port: 3001
    },
    server: {
        baseDir: 'dist',
        middleware: [historyApiFallback()],
        open: "local"
    },
    browser: 'google chrome',
    open: 'local'
});
```

And I run it like:

```
node tools/dist-server.js
```

BrowserSync starts but it does not open a new instance of google chrome.

Any idea hot to do it?

Comment: You have `open: 'local'` twice, you only need the root level one. That shouldn't prevent it from working, though.

Answer (score 0):

Your example works in OSX. Chrome opens to `http://localhost:3000`. Perhaps you have a permissions issue that's preventing chrome from being opened externally.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing

```
browser: 'google chrome'
```

by

```
browser: 'chrome'
```

works fine with your example...